# Chinese Pronunciation App

Tags: pronunciation, tones

I am curious whether there is some good app or a website for practicing pronunciation of Chinese tones.

There is a way to practice pronunciation on HelloChinese but I find the tone recognition quite inaccurate. For instance, I can say an entire sentence with the same tone, which is clearly wrong, and still the app would show half of the tones as correctly pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it's a good idea to rely on such apps. Try to mimic high quality recordings or even record yourself for comparison purposes.

Forvo is good for words and phrases, textbooks with an audio CD like Integrated Chinese, Učebnice čínské konverzace and such for whole sentences.

You can also try if some machine translators will get what you're saying by voice, but only for the lulz.

Comment: Thank you. Ďakujem. I will try to do the recordings and compare it with native speakers. It appears that Forvo is just great for that. I find it difficult pronouncing the 2nd tone and, less often, the 3rd tone, especially in combination with other tones.